# Running multiple tasks in one Service's method

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mvvm, async-await, mvvmcross

It is a good practice to have a simple methods, which returns tasks:

```
public class MessageService : IMessageService
{
    public Task<IEnumerable<Message>> DownloadMessagesTask()
    {
         return MyWebClient.GetMessages();
    }
```

Now, I'd like to add a caching to the local storage:

```
    public Task<bool> WriteMessagesTask(IEnumerable<Message> list)
    {
        return MyIsoStorageManager.Write(list);
    }
    // same for reading
```

Most naive way is to call them from viewmodel:

```
    public async void Init()
    {
         var result = await messageService.ReadMessagesTask();
         if (result == null)
         {
             MessagesList = await messageService.DownloadMessagesTask();
             var writingResult = await messageService.WriteMessagesTask(MessagesList);
         }
```

But how can I store this logic in a service, just to avoid code repeating in another viewmodels? Or should I keep service clean and call tasks in a viewmodel?

Comment: It's a good convention to suffix method names that return `Task` with `Async`

Comment: @RussCam I thought that the ones which returns `Task` should be suffixed by `*Task`

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx, specifically Naming, Parameters and Return Types

Comment: Wrap and combine your simple tasks into one service class. Task creation do have overhead.

Comment: @MikkoViitala they are already wrapped in MessageService. Now, i'm going to use them - and there's the question: where a logic should be stored?

Comment: Expose one method from your service and call it from VM. This method wraps what you now have in your async Init()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expose one method from your service that wraps what you now have in you `async void Init()` and call it from VM. You could also extract interface and inject that in your viewmodel (via constructor or property).

META

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyViewModel()
        :this(new Service())
    {}

    public MyViewModel(IService service)
    {
        Service = service;
        Initialize();
    }

    public IService Service { get; set; }

    private async void Initialize()
    {
        // Fire forget
        await Service.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

META

```
public interface IService
{
    // change if you need to return something
    Task DoSomething();
}

public Service : IService
{
    public async Task DoSomething()
    {
        var result = await ReadMessagesAsync();
        if (result == null)
        {
            var messages = await DownloadMessagesAsync();
            await WriteMessagesAsync(messages);
        }
    }

    // private read/write/download methods here...
}
```

Comment: I assume, your `Service` and `MessageService` are the one service?

Comment: Yes. Above is just "meta" written directly into SO.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you cold split these methods into some helper classes and use them in viewmodels as you see fit. Or if you already have some base viewmodel class (for INotifyPropertyChanged for example) you could move them there, assuming they are mainly for viewmodels.

Get rid of the void after async. Because it is "fire and forget", you essentially start the method but have no control over when it is completed. In some cases it is ok, but avoid it if you can.

Comment: Well, storing them in a helper class sounds like a workaround - i'm interested in "native" solution. Fixed void issue - indeed, usually i'm trying to avoid it.